# In next Project Middleware works on netlify but not on loaclhost

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have created a middleware.js file at the same level page (at root directory) which works when I deploy the project on netlify but it is not even triggering on localhost.

```
here is the code of middleware.js file

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const secretkey = "sm@234";
export function middleware(request) {
const key = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("secretkey");
const cookie = request.cookies.get("auth_dev");
if (key && key === secretkey) {
 const response = NextResponse.next();
 response.cookies.set("auth_dev", "OK");
 return response;
}
if (cookie === "OK") {
 return NextResponse.next();
}
// Check if the request has already been redirected
const redirected = request.cookies.get("redirected");
if (!redirected) {
  // Set a cookie to prevent infinite redirections
  const response = NextResponse.redirect(
  new URL("/underConstruction", request.url)
 );
  response.cookies.set("redirected", true);
  return response;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide more context of your issue, like the code of your middleware.js file